# What is it in Java standard library that Python's lacks?

Tags: java, python

I hear that the Java standard library is larger than that of Python. That makes me curious about what is missing in Python's?

Comment: CORBA is probably the most pointless thing which is part of Java's standard library - nobody uses it anymore, but it's too late to remove it because of Java's backward compatibility standards. It would have been better for it to be an external library. It's the org.omg.* packages in http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/overview-summary.html

Comment: @Tshepang OMG could stand for Oh My God! or Object Management Group :p Anyway, if I remember well, Java still depended on an external object broker, right?

Comment: @Esko I actually have worked on some new corba stuff not that long ago (2 years or so) and I'm very glad that it's still included. Though I wouldn't mind if it were an optional (but maintained) extra package.

Comment: @fortran That's not so strange. No-one in his or her right mind would use Corba for inter-java communication. You'd only use it if there absolutely was no other choice whatsoever anywhere.

Comment: @fortran I also have a faint memory, that internally Java uses CORBA for something, but I'm not fully sure about it. BTW, here is a nice article about why CORBA failed: http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=1142044

Comment: @Esko nice article, I already had the intuition of some of the causes were related with the complexity :-)

Answer (score 8):

The one flaw in Python imho is that Python lacks one real canonical method of deployment. (Yes there are good ones out there, but nothing that's really rock solid).

Which can hamper its adoption in some Enterprise environments.

Comment: Packaging and deployment are in dire need of help. There are some with a vision forward -- let's hope they succeed.

Answer (score 6):

Java provides a lot of varied implementations of interfaces for the basic types. Java has an ArrayList and single-linked-list and double-linked list, whereas Python just has a list. Java includes multiple Map implementations such as [TreeMap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) or [LinkedHashMap](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), whereas Python generally sticks to the single dict implementation. An [ordered dictionary was proposed](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0372/) is now part of Python 3.1, but in general, Java has a richer set of collections and base classes.

In defense of Python, however, the need for more rigorously defined base classes and interfaces is much less necessary with the dynamically-typed approach (where interfaces are often accepted implicitly).

Comment: Also don't forget Java's concurrency-aware collections in the java.util.concurrent package.

Comment: I would say that having just one implementation of the basic collection types is a side effect of supporting them as built-in types with syntax sugar around... Sincerely, I do prefer having just one kind of dictionary and being able to use {} for the constructor than having three or four types and using a more verbose syntax (same for lists).

Comment: There are also languages whose syntax is so flexible, that library types look like if they were built-in types. For example Scala.

Comment: With the introduction of [Abstract Base Classes](http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html) [many data structures](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#abcs-abstract-base-classes) have something similar to a formal interface.  Generally Python hasn't added data structures based on algorithm theory, but has tried to make the basic data structures as good as possible and then slowly added more structures for cases where existing structures really don't work, based on the idea that a well-tuned general structure often beats a more specific less-used structure.

Comment: @fortran That's fine as long as they way it's implemented happens to coincide with your exact use case. Admittedly a lot of the time it doesn't matter - but when you're dealing with (say) huge lists it's nice to be able to pick the implementation that's more efficient for your use case (adding/enumerating/searching/etc)

Comment: @Basic I talked about convenience of having a literal syntax for the constructors, but the beauty of Duck Typing is that you can still use different implementations of lists and dictionaries as long as they support the get/set and iteration methods and they will be (or should be if the code using them is not doing strong type checks) indistinguishable :)

Answer (score 4):

Python also comes *With Batteries Included*... The only place where I've felt Python lacking is a good GUI toolkit (no, TK doesn't compare to Swing xD).

Comment: @Matt, PyGTK is not part of stdlib.

Answer (score 3):

Python lacks a robust XML implementation (with full XSLT and XPATH support). The Python stdlib has a few decent implementations for working with XML (DOM parser, SAX parser, and a tree builder called ElementTree), but more advanced XML requires a third party library. I've used 4XSLT and now defer to LXML when I need to do some real XML work in Python.

Comment: I would concur with that, and add that in a related note that it's SOAP implementation is not strong. However, there are good third party (free) packages that pick up the slack. And often those end up as part of the standard lib.

Comment: The DOM parser (if you mean [xml.dom.minidom](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html)) is not good at all.  If you want to parse a document ElementTree is the only decent thing in the standard library.